# Ways of managing multiple versions of software

Tags: git, version-control

I'm writing an IDE that will support many languages. I'd like to have a separate "version" of the IDE for each language, to avoid having a confusing number of seemingly unrelated features. I'd also like not to have to make the same change on multiple codebases if the change applies to all languages.

Is there any way to do this, preferably using git but not necessarily?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I don't understand why you require "different versions" of your IDE for different programming languages. Why not let your IDE activate / deactivate different features for each language dynamically at run time (like any other "universal" IDE I know does )? Voting to close as "unclear".

Comment: You might want to research how JetBrains makes their IDEs - they have many language specific IDEs that share a lot of code. https://www.jetbrains.com/products.html#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having separate versions per language will result in a maintenance nightmare. You should also consider that development is often multi-language nowadays, so it might be better to use a plugin architecture with language specific code in the plugins.